# SSH connection fails due to permission issues

Tags: ssh, permissions

I have a Linux box whose password login is disabled and I can only SSH using the [Public Key Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_authentication#Authentication_using_Public_Key_Cryptography). The public keys are stored in `/home/user1/.ssh/autorized_keys`. I used to SSH using the private key and it was fine.

However I changed the permission of `/home/user1` directory to 777 and, since then, I'm having issues with login, I get the following error message:

[image]

I tried to change the permission of `.ssh` directory to 700 and `authorized_keys` to 600 but I'm still having issues. Any ideas on what's going on ?

Comment: try `644` on `authorized_keys` ?

Comment: what happened after you change the permission of `/home/user1` to be 700? do you manage to login?

Comment: No I can't, I keep getting the error in the attached screenshot

Comment: Did you repair the permissions of `/home/user1` per @Yaron's comment, not just `/home/user1/.ssh` ?

Comment: I changed the /home/user1 permission to 700  but it doesn't help.

Comment: now the /home/user1 has 700, .ssh has 700 and authorized_keys has 644 but still having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix your `/home` directory permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x root root
   ```
2. Fix your `/home/user1` directory permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x user user
   ```
3. Fix your `/home/user1/.ssh` directory permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   drwx------ user user
   ```
4. Fix your `/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys` file permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   -rw------- user user
   ```
5. Fix your `/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or other public key files permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   -rw-r--r-- user user
   ```
6. Fix your `/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa` or other private key files permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   -rw------- user user
   ```
7. Fix your `/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts` file permissions, check as follows:

   ```
   -rw-r--r-- user user
   ```

Comment: I don't have id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and know_hosts files. The public key is in the authorized_keys

Comment: how those permission takes effective? Is closing my ssh session enough for them to become effective?

Comment: @H.Z. You should just restart `sshd` service afterwards.